# Command to create nested and sequentially dated folders

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am a two day noobie & need some help. I want to create a folder on the Desktop called 2013 Dec. Vacation & have sequentially dated folders 2013-12-01 to 2013-12-31 nested inside the main folder. The following command works but it give an error message on days 10 to 31(A Subdirectory or File Already Exists.) Can someone refine this command.

Thanks

```
 for /l %a in (1,1,9) do md "C:\Users\b\Desktop\2013 Dec. Vacation\2013-12-0%a" & for /l %a in (10,1,31) do md "C:\Users\b\Desktop\2013 Dec. Vacation\2013-12-%a"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s treating your command as if it were

```
for /l %a in (1,1,9) do (
    md "C:\Users\b\Desktop\2013 Dec. Vacation\2013-12-0%a"
    for /l %a in (10,1,31) do md "C:\Users\b\Desktop\2013 Dec. Vacation\2013-12-%a"
)
```

so the second `FOR` loop is executed nine times.

Why not just do it as two lines?:

```
for /l %a in (1,1,9)  do md "C:\Users\b\Desktop\2013 Dec. Vacation\2013-12-0%a"
for /l %a in (10,1,31) do md "C:\Users\b\Desktop\2013 Dec. Vacation\2013-12-%a"
```

Or, if you really want to do it all on one line, add parentheses as shown below:

```
( for /l %a in (1,1,9) do md "C:\Users\b\Desktop\2013 Dec. Vacation\2013-12-0%a" )  &  for /l %a in (10,1,31) do md "C:\Users\b\Desktop\2013 Dec. Vacation\2013-12-%a"
```

Comment: Thanks for the lesson Scott. Adding the Parentheses suggestion was exactly what I wanted. Works great.

Comment: @user202151: Glad to help (and welcome to Super User).

Comment: @user202151: May I draw your attention to [the **How do I ask questions?** section](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask) of the Super User FAQ (Frequently Asked Questions) –– “When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the **accepted answer** by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.”  If you do that, we both benefit.  After you have earned some more [reputation](http://superuser.com/faq#reputation), you can also [vote up](http://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) helpful answers by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer.